# ¿Cómo incluir una librería en Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, librería, error404

Tengo que usar las librerías `<unistd.h>` y `<sys/io.h>` pero no tengo ni idea como bajarlas.

Por si no pueden ver la foto, las líneas son:

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/io.h>
```

Y el mensaje de error es:

> código: E1696 Descipción: No se puede abrir el archivo origen.

Para ambas líneas de código.

Comment: Holi, no, en windows!

Comment: Ese compilador me va a permitir acceder al hardware de la máquina? Porque tengo que acceder al RTC mediante los ports, para leer la hora, la fecha y setear alarmas

Comment: Esas son librerias de unix. No las tienes disponibles en windows. Si lo quieres hacer en windows, tendras que encontrar los equivalentes en `Windows.h`

Comment: Oh, bueno, muchas gracias! Voy a probar hacer eso.
Gracias